# Different behavior of EnableStatic on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c++, windows, cluster-computing, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I wrote C++ program running on 2 cluster nodes which should add \ remove a virtual IP from the network card on each node (following some logic I've wrote..).
For that, I use EnableStatic method of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390383(v=vs.85).aspx).

On that program I have 2 buttons, "Release VIP" and "Acquire VIP".
I use RDP to connect these nodes (using the permanent IP, not the VIP).

For Release VIP I call: EnableStatic({ "1.1.1.5" }, { "255.255.0.0" });

For Acquire VIP I call: EnableStatic({ "1.1.1.5", "1.1.1.80" }, { "255.255.0.0", "255.255.0.0" });

(For this example 1.1.1.80 is the VIP)

When I did it on Windows 2012 everything worked fine and I was able to add \ remove the virtual IP.

Now, on Windows 2016, my RDP is losing connection for 2-3 seconds as a result of the change in the VIP on the network card (both add and remove..).

I know that in this API documentation Microsoft wrote that RDP should lose connection but I wonder:

1. Why it didn't happened in Windows 2012?
2. Did they made any change?
3. Maybe I do something wrong?

And more important:

1. Does it have other effect except the RDP losing connection that I should know of??
2. Is there a better API to use?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ohh great you are so smart thanks Hong Shmong.
Someone else can help?

Comment: Is it really correct to use 2 IPs on the same subnet?

Comment: Its alias IP, I want that accessing to my cluster will be with the same IP (the virtual IP).

I don't know any risk to use 2 IPs on the same subnet, maybe I miss something?

And again, I'm counting on the working cluster I have on server 2012